# Python TypeError: must be string, not int

Tags: python

I have a very simple script where I am executing 4 other scripts.

Line 17 throws this error: `TypeError: must be string, not int`

This is line 17 in its entirety:

```
execfile(c)
```

It executes the first two scripts (`a` & `b`) with no issue but fails on `c`. If I comment out the first two script lines, it will run line 17 successfully.

Any ideas?

The entire script:

```
import datetime

today = str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))

a = r'\\server\Scheduled_Scripts\PowerBI_part1.py'
b = r'\\server\Scheduled_Scripts\PowerBI_part2.py'
c = r'\\server\Scheduled_Scripts\PowerBI_part3.py'
d = r'\\server\Scheduled_Scripts\PowerBI_part4.py'

print "Starting at " + today

print "Executing part 1..."
execfile(a)
print "Executing part 2..."
execfile(b)
print "Executing part 3..."
execfile(c)
print "Executing part 4..."
execfile(d)

print "Complete at " + today
```

Comment: Looks like either `a` or `b` is overwriting your `c`.

Comment: It would be useful to see scripts a, b and c.

Comment: Do you mean the previous script (b) isn't finishing before c is executed?

Comment: @Aran-Fey well according to the docs that shouldn't happen unless `locals()` is explicitly passed to `execfile` (if I understand it correctly that is)

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: If you use a `global` named today that would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Check for naming clashes between variables in your different scripts. Try only running it with `a` and only running it with `b` to see which one caused the problem, and then look through the two scripts. If they're both running in the same namespace, it's very likely you used the same variable name or function name twice, and something that should be an string was declared an integer in a previous script.

Also, have you considered grouping everything into functions and then just importing the other scripts?

Answer (score 0):

`c` is declared in top level script, so it is automatically member of the `globals()` dictionary. That means that if any of the 2 first scripts contain a line `c=1` (or any integer value), your global `c` will be overwritten.

As you do not want that the subscripts change any of your globals, you could try to pass a new and empty dict:

```
print "Executing part 1..."
execfile(a, {})
print "Executing part 2..."
execfile(b, {})
print "Executing part 3..."
execfile(c, {})
print "Executing part 4..."
execfile(d, {})
```

As the subscript start with an empty global dictionnary, that can no longer overwrite variables from the top level script

Comment: This was the issue. "c" was a variable in one of the scripts. I changed the exec variables to moe, larry, curly, and shemp respectively and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much!